# Маршрутизация и проброс портов

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, iptables, openvpn

Я понимаю, что много источников и подробных описаний, я их прочитал, попробовал, но у меня не работает. Вероятно, это мои кривые руки, но тем не менее спрошу.

Есть сервер ubuntu 18.04 с белым IP(eth1 123.123.123.123). Этот сервер работает сервером OpenVPN(tun0 раздает адреса 10.10.10.0/24) и к нему подключаются клиенты.
Форвардинг на сервере включен еще на этапе настройки OpenVPN.
Одним из клиентов этого OpenVPN сервера является роутер(tun0 адрес 10.10.10.5), подключенный к интернету через 4G модем с серым адресом. К этому роутеру подключено 3 машины, находящиеся в локальной сети роутера(192.168.1.0/24). Проброс портов на роутере я настроил и если я подключаюсь к OpenVPN серверу, то имею к ним доступ.

Нужно иметь аналогичный доступ к этим серверам, обращаясь на белый IP сервера по разным портам(допустим, для доступа к 1 серверу использовать порт 3457). Пытался настроить через iptables по разным статьям(естественно с редактированием интерфейсов и адресов из примеров под мою ситуацию), но не заработало.

Что делал:

1) Разрешил форвард SYN с eth1 на tun0 на сервере по порту 3457.

2) Разрешил форвард трафика с eth1 на tun0 и обратно.

3) Направил прероутинг при обращении на порт 3457 по eth1 с перенаправлением на адрес роутера 10.10.10.5 по тому же порту.

4) Ответы от роутера 10.10.10.5 по порту 3457 перенаправляю обратно на белый IP сервера 123.123.123.123.

И вот этот набор не работает. Доступа через белый IP сервера к локальным серверам нет. Скажу еще раз, что если подключусь к VPN, то обращаясь к IP роутера внутри VPN по порту 3457 имею доступ к локальному серверу.

Подскажите, где я косячу или в чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: если интерфейс `tun0` создаётся программой *openvpn*, то у вас не получится его использовать. обращайтесь к маршрутизатору по тому ip-адресу, по которому он реально доступен с вашего сервера (и, естественно, через тот интрефейс, за которым закреплён маршрут к этому ip-адресу).

Answer (score 0):

На сервере:

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 3457 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.5`

и всё. Обратная трансляция выполняется автоматически.
Но:

1. Сервер должен пропускать пакеты.
2. Роутер должен пробрасывать пакеты на нужный хост внутренней сети.
3. Роутер должен посылать пакеты-ответы от того хоста через туннель серверу.

Пункты 1, 3 контролируются `tcpdump`ом на сервере:

`tcpdump -i tun0 -n -p port 3457`

Таким образом, из вашего списка вызывают вопросы пп. 1 и 4. 1 — потому что неизвестно, есть ли правило ESTABLISHED, пропускающее пакеты *без* SYN.